Streaming audio data from my serverless(Vercel) next.js app to a storage (Azure blob storage for example)
What is the best way to stream in realtime audio that my users record on my next.js app directly to a storage?
As you know if you are using vercel you do not have a server so I need to find a workaround.
I can use a websocket but then I will need to use a cloud function in order to upload the audio to the storage.
Is there a way to upload it directly from the websocket?
